# Allow FontAwesome icons retrieval with Spring Security

Tags: spring, angular, spring-boot

I'm building an Angular app with Spring Boot backend. I integrated Spring Security and I added FontAwesome dependency like following in Angular `package.json`

```
"dependencies": {
     .....
     "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
     .....
}
```

The problem is that Spring Security keeps blocking FA's icons retrieval.
[image]
My Spring Security configuration is like follows :

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().
                authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/","/generate-token", "/signup","/config","/saveConfig/","/get/file/*").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/assets/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/*.js").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/*.css").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/fonts/*").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/resources/*").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http
                .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

How to allow FontAwesome in Spring Security ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are allowing any request that matches '/fonts/*' to be anonymous, you request for font awesome does not match that url pattern, so either move FontAwesome under fonts folder.
Or add a rule for FontAwesome

```
...
.antMatchers("/fontawesome*").permitAll()
```

Comment: It works ! Didn't know that we can use such pattern (anystring*). Thank you :) !